# Is this a correct solution to determining which of two people is the liar using one question?

Tags: logic, puzzle

I am a newbie to Stack-Exchange and if there is any problem in my question -- I apologize beforehand .

I was working my way through some Propositional Logic Questions in [Discrete Maths by Rosen](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flipkart.com%2Fdiscrete-mathematics-its-applications-combinatorics-graph-theory-english-7th%2Fp%2Fitmdwxxszhczjrnf&ei=Oo2ZVIeqGJHluQT32IHICQ&usg=AFQjCNGMqBbPuopaBnOUnxErGEfGBONe5w&bvm=bv.82001339,d.c2E) , when I came across the following question :

> An explorer is captured by a group of cannibals. There are two types
>   of cannibals—those who always tell the truth and those who always lie.
>   The cannibals will barbecue the explorer unless he can determine
>   whether a particular cannibal always lies or always tells the truth.
>   He is allowed to ask the cannibal exactly one question.
>
> Find a question that the explorer can use to determine whether the
>   cannibal always lies or always tells the truth.

**My Solution :**

*If I were to ask you whether you are a liar, would you answer yes?*

- The honest person would say NO.
- The liar would say YES (due to double negation).

**Doubt :**

Am I correct in saying my answer will work? It almost seems too simple.

Comment: Thanks @Thumbnail - how do we do the greying area thing ?

Comment: It's hinted *block quote*.

Comment: If you're patient enough you can watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9uqPeIYMik), otherwise you can read [this dialog](https://outsideofadream.wordpress.com/2012/11/12/kaspar-hauser/)...

Comment: I would ask  "is 1 plus 1 equal to 2?" Liar "no", honest person  "yes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have exactly the right idea. You force the liars to make two negations.  This question works just fine, as will others, as long as they are "honest" liars.

Comment: Thanks @RossMillikan . Also can you explain the bit about honest liars -- I am not sure that I get it ...

Comment: Basically you have to believe that they will follow the logic and lie every time, including hypothetical cases.  In popular parlance a liar could be anybody who tries to deceive you. At that point you can't necessarily trust the answer.

Comment: Got it @RossMilkman :)

Comment: Suppose that the liar says that he is a liar.  Then he has told the truth about himself and thus not lied.  But then he is not a liar, and thus his statement about himself is false, and consequently he is a liar.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think this will also work-"if I can find whether you are a liar or truther will you stop barbecue me?"

Liar will say No.

Truther will say yes.

Answer (score 0):

The gist of the answer is to actually ask a question within a question.

Let's break down the following revealing question:

*"If I were to ask you whether you are a liar, would you answer yes?"*

Here, indeed, we have two questions that are:

1. Are you a liar
2. Would you answer yes to question 1?

By asking the second question, the liar is revealed. The honest would not respond differently. Let's take a look by asking these two questions to the two cannibals.

**ASKING THE LIAR:**

1. Are you a liar?

- Honest answer (he wouldn't say this): YES
- Actual answer (negation of honest answer): NO

2. Would you answer yes to question 1?

- Honest answer (he wouldn't say this): NO
- Actual answer (negation of honest answer): YES

**ASKING THE THRUTFUL:**

1. Are you a liar?

- Honest answer: NO
- Actual answer: NO

2. Would you answer yes to question 1?

- Honest answer: NO
- Actual answer: NO

So the honest cannibal will say NO consistently, whereas the liar will lie about a lie, which will reveal him.